# Validate multiple textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have this code that validates if `ContentPlaceHolder1_locationTextBox` has text in it before `newIndex` can become 3.

```
if ((newIndex === 3 && $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_locationTextBox").val() == "")) {
            $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_locationLabelV').show();

            return false;
        }
        else {
            $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_locationLabelV').hide();
        }
```

However I also have `ContentPlaceHolder1_countryTextBox` & `ContentPlaceHolder1_seaTextBox` on the page with thier respective labels, how can I modify the script so that it validates against all textboxes?

I tried adding a horrible **or** statement however this was causing the page to freeze. What s the best method to check against all three textboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add class for all inputs, example: validate

After you can create JS function. You can fire this function as you wish.

```
function check(){
    $('.validate').each(function(){
        label = $("label[for='"+$(this).attr('id')+"']");
        if ((newIndex === 3 && $(this).val() == "")) {
            label.show();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            label.hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate(value) {

   if ...
     //show div
   else ...
     // hide div

}

$("input[type='text']").each(function(){

   //value from input text field
   var myval = $(this).val();

   //call validation function
   validate(myval);

});
```